# How to define an elements style using CSS to be on top of an other? Why in my case z-index isn't effective?

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float

I have this style on an `<img>` tag.

```
position: absolute;
margin: -477px 0 0 581px;
z-index: 1000;
```

and near this element I have a div with this style:

```
position: relative;
margin: 100px 0 0 70px;
z-index: 1054;
bottom: 119px;
width: 67%;
```

The problem is that the image is always over the div although I change the divs z-index to a higher number.

What can I do that the div will be in top of the image?

Comment: please, provide your code in jsFiddle.net to see what exactly you have

Comment: I have no permission to do so.
If there is a way to send you in private so no prob.

Comment: I think it is with the div's "position: relative;" part. Changing it to absolute for example would allow the text to be on top. http://jsfiddle.net/KuPhr/

Comment: I see. 
Is there any way to solve this issue without changing the position? 
I am working on a built website that every "position" change is critical to the design.

Comment: @Hatul Is my assumption correct, that you can not edit the DOM, only the CSS?

Comment: I can edit everything. It's for the website of the company I work in..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [..]and near this element I have a div with this style

`near` is ambiguous and makes it sound like your issue is due to a misinterpretation of [**stacking context**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

Elements are layered based on a number of factors, crucially they can be *generalised* as:

1. Elements that are placed later in the DOM (later in your HTML) appear 'over' those placed before
2. Elements with a higher `z-index` appear 'over' those with a lower `z-index`*
3. Points 1 & 2 only apply to elements within the same parent-child hierarchy**

<sup>*In order for z-indexes to work as anticipated, a `position` also needs to be assigned, relative to a shared parent element</sup>

<sup>** May be additionally affected by parent `overflow`</sup>

As such, it sounds like your issue is either that your elements arent children of the same parent element. Or the element you wish to appear 'on top' is placed *before* the other element in your HTML.

Comment: Sharp distinction :) !  

Yes, The given website I am working on is given to me to make it mobile responsive and it's built badly.  
I'm looking for a way to prevent of messing around the structure an try to work it out like this. 

and as @Alex said in the comment of the main post, and given the example... It's because the position. 

I will be happy to hear if you have an alternate solution for this issue. 
Worst case scenario I will work on the website design from the beginning :( .